# Allowtransparency=true doesn't render the WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winapi, winforms-interop

I am using tabcontrol in a forms application where I want to show a WPF window from other process in one tab. I am able to show the WPF window with following code but if I set `Allowtransparency = true` in WPF window, it doesn't get rendered inside tab. Can anybody explain me why is it happening?

```
    void Form1_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            var process = Process.Start(@"wpfWindow.exe");
            process.WaitForInputIdle();

            while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, tabPage1.Handle);


            SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 0, (int)tabPage1.ClientSize.Width, (int)tabPage1.ClientSize.Height, WindowsConstants.SWP_NOZORDER | WindowsConstants.SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }
```

Comment: try ResizeMode="NoResize" instead of Allowtransparency=true

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). Plot spoiler: *"It's one of those 'if you don't already know what the consequences are, then you are not smart enough to do it correctly' things. You must first become the master of the rules before you can start breaking them."*

Comment: @IInspectable Well,Consider this as an initial attempt towards becoming master of rules and try to answer the question specifically.

Comment: Your first step is to understand the [asynchronous input model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130604-00/?p=4173). And to answer your question: What you have **will** inevitably break, at some point. Your application will stop responding to input.

Comment: @viveknuna Thanks,but I need transparency in my WPF window.

Comment: @TRS was it working with  ResizeMode="NoResize"?

Comment: @viveknuna It works in all conditions except Allowtransparency=true